# Getting Error: 500 error when using AJAX POST to C# Webmethod

Tags: c#, ajax, webmethod

I created a webmethod that returns an HTML string that is attached to a `div` at the end of a drop operation.

The first iteration of the WebMethod was named TestMethod, which worked great.  When I literally changed the name of the method, the server returned a 500 error.

On the Dash1.aspx.cs page:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetPanelHTML(string id)
        {
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            string strHTML = da.CreateVPPanel(id);

            return strHTML;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string TestMethod(string id)
        {
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            string strHTML = da.CreateVPPanel(id);

            return strHTML;
        }
```

On the client page:

```
    const dropzoneid = e.target.id;
    var idparm = '{ id: ' + panelID + ' }';
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Dash1.aspx/GetPanelHTML',
        data: idparm,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d);
            $('#' + dropzoneid).html(data.d);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert('failure ' + response.d);
        }
    });
```

If I change the url to `/Dash1.aspx/TestMethod`, it works.  Both methods are exactly the same.

I published the project and decompiled the page dll and both methods exist.

Comment: Any reason you’re using static methods here? Try clean and rebuild too? 

Can you please post your working code and your code that’s not working?

Comment: I tried Cleaning and Rebuilding with no results.  I'm using webmethods because I need server data after a drag and drop event.  In the code behind I have two webmethods,  One named TestMethod, the other named GetPanelHTML.  When I call TestMethod, everything works.  That name is not descriptive so I created the GetPanelHTML method.  When I call that method from the ajax url, I get the 500 server error.

Comment: New developments:  I created a third WebMethod which took 2 arguments in the signature.  That method failed as well until I doubled quoted the input values in the JSON input.  Appears to be functioning correctly, but more testing is required.

Comment: Hard to comment further without seeing everything sorry. Happy to help with more examples